# Two-color linear gradient positioning with PIL Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gradient

Perhaps it is something easy for many.
I am trying to create a background from 2 colors. The intention is that it starts on the left with one color and ends with another color on its right side (horizontally.)

the question is that I have from corner to corner. and what I'm looking for is that it is side by side.

My code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def interpolate(f_co, t_co, interval):
    det_co =[(t - f) / interval for f , t in zip(f_co, t_co)]
    for i in range(interval):
        yield [round(f + det * i) for f, det in zip(f_co, det_co)]


imgsize=(1920,1080)
gradient = Image.new('RGBA', imgsize, color=0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(gradient)

f_co = (253, 46, 216)
t_co = (23, 214, 255)
for i, color in enumerate(interpolate(f_co, t_co, gradient.width * 2)):
    draw.line([(i, 0), (0, i)], tuple(color), width=1)
gradient.show()
```

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb00f.png

Comment: From left to right?

Comment: Yes that's how it is

Answer (score 4):

For left to right, the easiest fix is to just modify the `draw.line` coordinates from

```
draw.line([(i, 0), (0, i)], tuple(color), width=1)
```

to

```
draw.line([(i, 0), (i, gradient.height)], tuple(color), width=1)
```

and adjust `gradient.width * 2` in the `interpolate()` call to just `gradient.width`.
The result is

[image]

For top to bottom, you'll need to adjust the argument to `interpolate()` to use `gradient.height` and do

```
draw.line([(0, i), (gradient.width, i)], tuple(color), width=1)
```

and the result is
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much is what exactly I needed
I've tried to vote for your help, but it requires 15 reputation. When I get it I will give you the positive button

Answer (score 2):

I think I would take a different approach rather than drawing 3,840 lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define start and end colours and image height and width
colourA=[255, 0, 255]
colourB=[0, 255, 255]
h, w = 1080, 1920

# Make output image
gradient = np.zeros((h,w,3), np.uint8)

# Fill R, G and B channels with linear gradient between two end colours
gradient[:,:,0] = np.linspace(colourA[0], colourB[0], w, dtype=np.uint8)
gradient[:,:,1] = np.linspace(colourA[1], colourB[1], w, dtype=np.uint8)
gradient[:,:,2] = np.linspace(colourA[2], colourB[2], w, dtype=np.uint8)

# Save result
Image.fromarray(gradient).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: That'll be faster for sure, but far from OP's original approach (and hard to adapt for arbitrary angles) :)

Comment: and in case one of the 2 sides is transparent?
Suppose it would go one color until it becomes totally transparent

Comment: You can easily add gradient transparency as well. Just add a 4th element to the colours so they are RGBA instead of RGB, make the result 4-channel with `gradient = np.zeros((h,w,4), np.uint8)` and add an extra line to make a linear gradient in the alpha channel `gradient[:,:,3] = np.linspace(colourA[3], colourB[3], w, dtype=np.uint8)`